# How to add a product image programatically in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I had a problem adding a product image programatically. Here's the code I used:

```
$product->setImage('/test.jpg')
    ->setSmallImage('/test.jpg')
    ->setThumbnail('/test.jpg')
    ->addImageToMediaGallery('/test.jpg', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false);

$product = $productRepository->save($product);
```

When run, it throws this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'There is no MediaGalleryEntryConverter for given type' in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media/EntryConverterPool.php:48
```

when I save product and try to update like this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5249): `$product->save();`

Throws this error:

```
Fatal error:Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed in .../vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Simple.php:61
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for if someone needs future, This is theme configuration file problem when I update 2.0.x to 2.1 forgot to update all necessary theme files settings to 2.1, after that my problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should initialize the gallery first:

```
->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) 
->addImageToMediaGallery('/test.jpg', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false);
```

Comment: How to set image label? can you please explain?

Comment: idea???@ Fabian

Answer (score 1):

In your back-end, go to Content > Design > Configuration. Then set the themes of your front-end. Save it. Then the issue should go away.

Cheers,

Renato.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the new product gallery management classes for Magento 2.1 here:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Gallery/*`

Answer (score 0):

```
        $baseImage = $value[19];
        $singleImage = explode(',', $baseImage);
        $addtionalImages = $value[20];
        $totalImages = explode(',', $addtionalImages);
        $baseImagePath = $this->dir->getRoot() . '/' . DirectoryList::PUB . '/media/import/' . $value[19];
        if (count($singleImage)>0) {
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($baseImagePath, ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'], false, false);
        }
        if (count($totalImages)>1) {
            for ($i=1; $i<count($totalImages); $i++) {
                $addImagePath = $this->dir->getRoot() . '/' . DirectoryList::PUB . '/media/import/' . $totalImages[$i];
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($addImagePath, [], false, false);
            }
        }
```